# Single method that can pull values from different objects that derive from NameObjectCollectionBase?

Tags: c#, collections, key-value

I'm working with several collections that derive from `NameObjectCollectionBase`.  Is there a way to extract key/value pairs from classes that derive from `NameObjectCollectionBase` in a single method?

I can get the keys in the collection, but I'm unable to get values.  So far I've tried methods accepting both `NameObjectCollectionBase` as well as `IEnumerable<object>`:

```
private void Test1(NameObjectCollectionBase coll) {
    foreach(var key in coll) {
        var value = coll[key]; //doesn't work
    }
}
//Produces this error:
//Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase'

private void Test2(IEnumerable<object> coll) {
    foreach(var key in coll) {
        var value = coll[key]; //doesn't work
    }
}
//Produces this error:
//Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Generic.Collections.IEnumerable<object>'
```

I see `NameObjectCollectionBase` has methods for retrieving items from the underlying collection, but those methods are protected for the objects I receive into the method.

**EDIT: The extraction method doesn't have to be via brackets.  I'm really just looking for any way to do this generically.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after more experimentation, I finally settled on a T4 Template.  Although, admittedly, after all this I'd have to agree with anyone who said it'd be easier just to have a method to handle each different container.

Anyway.  Basically, this template pulls all the public children of NameObjectCollectionBase that have a Get(string) method signature and a string or object return type, then stamps out a Convert method for each matching class.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
<#
//exclusions that don't return a value from Get(string) method.
//var exclusions = new List<string> { "HttpCookieCollection" };
var types = GetAllSubTypesOf(typeof(NameObjectCollectionBase));//.Where(t=>!exclusions.Contains(t.Name));
foreach (var type in types.GroupBy(t => t.Namespace).Select(t => t.FirstOrDefault())) {
    var ns = type.Namespace;
#>
using <#= ns #>;
<#
}
#>

namespace SomeNamespace {
public class NameObjectCollectionBaseConverter {
<#
    foreach(var type in types) {
        var argType = type.Name;
    #>
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(<#= argType #> coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
    <#
    }
#>  
}
}
<#+
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllSubTypesOf(Type parent)
{
    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) { 
        foreach (var t in a.GetTypes()) {
            var methodInfo = t.GetMethod("Get", new [] { typeof(string) });

            if (
                t.IsSubclassOf(parent)
                && t.IsPublic
                && methodInfo != null
                && (
                    methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(string)
                    || methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(object)
                )
            ) {
                yield return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
#>
```

The output of the template is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace SomeNamespace {
public class NameObjectCollectionBaseConverter {
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(NameValueCollection coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(WebHeaderCollection coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(HttpApplicationStateBase coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(HttpApplicationStateWrapper coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(HttpApplicationState coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> Convert(HttpClientCertificate coll) {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = coll.Keys;
        foreach(var key in keys) {
            var strKey = key.ToString();
            var value = coll.Get(strKey).ToString();
            keyValues.Add(strKey, value);
        }

        return keyValues;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NameObjectCollectionBase` does not provide an overload for the brackets (as far as I can see in the documentation). From what I can tell, it's meant to for you to provide the implementation of a the brackets if you need them.

Take a look at this example:

```
  public Object this[ String key ]  {
      get  {
         return( this.BaseGet( key ) );
      }
      set  {
         this.BaseSet( key, value );
      }
  }
```

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would recommend using a `Dictionary<string, string>` or `NameValueCollection` in this case, since it has the functionality you are looking for. It doesn't look like NameObjectCollectionBase provides any useful public methods in your case.

Also, you cannot access `IEnumerable<T>` via brackets. You can only obtain elements using `ElementAt(int)`.

Comment: Well, doesn't have to be using the brackets, that's just one of the things I tried.  I'm really just looking for ANY way to generically grab the values from the collection of any object deriving from NameObjectCollectionBase.

Comment: Hmm. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase(v=vs.110).aspx . It seems like most of the methods are Protected. You could just treat it like an IEnumerable. I'll update my answer with a solution.

Comment: I've taken a closer look. You cannot do this with `NameObjectCollectionBase`. It is by design done such that it ONLY exposes keys and must be inherited by a concrete class to obtain the values. It doesn't seem like `NameObjectCollectionBase` was ever intended to be used generic way, though that is not a very good design choice. Can you use Dictionary<string, string>? `NameObjectCollectionBase` is pretty obscure and there are better key-value collections in .NET.

Comment: Hmm, I kinda figured.  I can't switch to a Dictionary, but I guess I will just write a method to handle each derivation of NameObjectCollectionBase :(  Thanks, though.

Comment: Was NameObjectCollectionBase chosen by design? If not go yell at the programmer who didn't do their research into NameObjectCollectionBase and make them fix it. Otherwise it could be that by design they didn't want you to be able to extract the values.